# Returning a string to an output field of type "number" for user error javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, error-handling

I'm working on a project to get the hang of javascript and html5.

Right now I have two text fields, `input_a` and `input_b`. I have one output field which will use these two numbers (can be whole or floating point) and will do a calculation on them and return that to the output field. For simplicity (ignoring CSS files) here is how this is set up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
            <title>JS Test</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </head>
        <script>
            function select_formula() {
                track_a = input_a.valueAsNumber;
                track_b = input_b.valueAsNumber;
                if(track_a > 200.0 || track_a < 0.0) {
                    console.log("Number must be between 0 BPM and 200 BPM");
                    return false;
                }
                if(track_b > 200.0 || track_b < 0.0) {
                    console.log("Number must be between 0 BPM and 200BPM");
                    return false;
                }
                if(track_a > track_b) {
                    return "((track_a - track_b) / track_a) * 100";
                } else if(track_a < track_b) {
                    return "((track_a - track_b) / track_b) * 100";
                } else {
                    return "0.0";
                }
            }
        </script>
    <body>
        <header>
                <h1>JS Test</h1>
        </header>

        <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value=eval(select_formula());">
                    Track A: <input name="input_a" id="input_a" type="number" step="0.01" min="0.0" max="200.0" placeholder="Track A"><br/>
                    Track B: <input name="input_b" id="input_b" type="number" step="0.01" min="0.0" max="200.0" placeholder="Track B"><br/>
                    <br />
                    Output: <output name="o" step="0.01" value="0.00" for="a b"></output>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thankfully right now no one can input a string into the text field because my input has a type of `number`. However, I wanted the output to show the error message `"Number must be between 0 BPM and 200 BPM"` if someone enters an invalid number outside of this range.

As of right now I can create an `alert()`, however I don't really need to annoy the user and go that far with the error. So is there anyway to send my error to the output? I'm brand new to JavaScript so I'm just trying to follow lots of different tutorials at this point. Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most simple way - you would want to have a div that you will use to append the error to it.
Something like:

```
   <script>
        function isValid(track_a, track_b) {
           if(track_a > 200.0 || track_a < 0.0) {
                return "Number must be between 0 BPM and 200 BPM";
            }
            if(track_b > 200.0 || track_b < 0.0) {
                return "Number must be between 0 BPM and 200BPM";
            }
            return "";
       }

       function calculate(track_a, track_b) {
            if(track_a > track_b) {
                return "((track_a - track_b) / track_a) * 100";
            } else if(track_a < track_b) {
                return "((track_a - track_b) / track_b) * 100";
            } else {
                return "0.0";
            }
        }

      function main() {
            track_a = input_a.valueAsNumber;
            track_b = input_b.valueAsNumber;

            var message = isValid(track_a, track_b);
            if (message !== "")
                 $('#result').text(message);
           else {
                 var result = calculate(track_a, track_b);
                 $('#result').text(result);
           }
      }
  </script>
<body>
        <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value=eval(main());">
                    Track A: <input name="input_a" id="input_a" type="number" step="0.01" min="0.0" max="200.0" placeholder="Track A"><br/>
                    Track B: <input name="input_b" id="input_b" type="number" step="0.01" min="0.0" max="200.0" placeholder="Track B"><br/>
                    <br />
                    <div id="result"></div>
                    Output: <output name="o" step="0.01" value="0.00" for="a b"></output>
        </form>
```

But I think you need a wider background.

Please check out [AngularJS tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) - which is currently the popular JavaScript framework to work with on the client side.

Comment: Now I'm having trouble making that number appear in the `output` text box. Right now it appears above it. I've tried moving the div, changing the `output` id, and much more, but nothing seems to work. How can I put `result` as the `output`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `type="range"` input, it will limit numbers range which user can input. Also range input will increase usability for mobile users.
Otherwise if you want user to be able input by typing, you can override input number with js and you won't need to output error message.

```
    <script>
        message = "";
        function select_formula() {
            track_a = input_a.valueAsNumber;
            track_b = input_b.valueAsNumber;
            if (track_a > 200) {
                input_a.value = 200;
            } else if (track_a < 0) {
                input_a.value = 0;
            } else if (track_b > 200) {
                input_b.value = 200;
            } else if (track_b < 0) {
                input_b.value = 0;
            }

            if(track_a > track_b) {
                return "((track_a - track_b) / track_a) * 100";
            } else if(track_a < track_b) {
                return "((track_a - track_b) / track_b) * 100";
            } else {
                return "0.0";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

In case you want to inform user with error message, just add error message dedicated tag. `<span>` or `<div>` which will be invisible by default and set it visible with js on error event.